# How to know jpeg format without decoding entire image (android)

Tags: java, android, jpeg

Is there any way to on android to know JPEG format without decoding the complete image?
By format I mean Baseline, Progressive etc.

Comment: This seems too low level, so I'd say there is no already available way. Why would you need to know such _implementation detail_ anyway?

Comment: I am trying to display very large JPEG files (30000x30000). The baseline (widely used format) format JPEG can be displayed by setting inSampleSize option before calling BitmapFactory.decodeStream(). However progressive format JPEG needs to be decoded fully by native code (skia, libjpeg). a fully decoded image of this size will take hundreds of megabytes, hence many other apps are killed by oom-killer and ultimately there is no image to display.

Comment: Well, you have a valid reason after all, a leaked implementation detail...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. From file name extension i.e.  *.jpg or *.jpeg
2. [Magic numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29). Most file formats have some special bytes at
   beginning of file, which denote the type of that file.
3. Rest of detailed information is interleaved in [EXIF data](http://gvsoft.homedns.org/exif/exif-explanation.html), you will have to read a part of the file for that.
4. Use [Markers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG#Syntax_and_structure) which divide file into segments, `0xFF, 0xC0` indicate baseline DCT, `0xFF, 0xC2` indicate progressive DCT. Also, if file has more that one start of scan markers, `0xFF, 0xDA` it is a progressive jpeg. See if you hit these byte sequences in your file.

Comment: What I need is additional information about JPEG file, whether it is baseline or progressive